# Scala 3 - Extract Tuple of wrappers and InverseMap on First Order Type

Tags: scala, tuples, dotty, scala-3

I am trying to create a function, which takes a tuple of higher-kinded types and applies a function to the types within the higher-kinded types.

In the example below, there is a `trait Get[A]` which is our higher-kinded type.  There is also a tuple of Get's: `(Get[String],Get[Int])` as well as function from `(String,Int) => Person`.

Scala-3 has a Match-Type called InverseMap which converts the type (Get[String], Get[Int]) into what is essentially the type (String,Int).

So the ultimate goal is to write a function which can take a tuple with any number of `Get[_]` types and a function whose input matches the InserveMap types and finally return a `Get[_]`, where the wrapped type is the result of the function.

I have attempted to create a function called `genericF` below to show the desired behavior, though it may not be correct -- but I think it does at least show the proper intent.

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
  trait Get[A] {
    def get: A
  }
  case class Put[A](get: A) extends Get[A]
    
  val t: (Get[String], Get[Int]) = (Put("Bob"), Put(42))
  
  val fPerson: (String,Int) => Person = Person.apply _
  
  def genericF[T<:Tuple,I<:Tuple.InverseMap[T,Get],B](f: I => B, t: T): Get[B] = ???
  val person: Get[Person] = genericF(fPerson, t)
```

I have set up a Scastie here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OleTraveler/QIyNHPLHQIKPv0lgsYbujA/23

Comment: I don't think `Get` is an HKT - it has a type parameter, but that parameter is not itself a type constructor

Comment: Well, for one, `fPerson` doesn't take a 2-tuple, it takes two parameters, so I guess you want another pair of parentheses there

Comment: I believe `Get` is a first-order type because you can create a proper type by passing in a type to the type parameter, eg `Get[String]` is a proper type.

Comment: In Scala-3, Tuple is a generic representation for a tuple with 0 or more elements, so no more parenthesis are needed.  I'm hoping to create genericF to be able to handle a Tuple of any size, not just the size of 2 shown in the example.

Comment: @TravisStevens Parenthesis are not needed in method parameters: you can call `extract(Put("Bob"), Put(42))` or `extract((Put("Bob"), Put(42)))`. But types `(String,Int) => Person` and `((String,Int)) => Person` are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is almost [compiling](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZQP4hCLxRO64zRsle4NvbA) already - the only thing is that `fPerson` is of type `(String, Int) => Person` instead of `((String, Int)) => Person` (taking a tuple instead of 2 separate parameters).

The solution below this one is not nice, although it is perhaps more efficient for TupleXXL's. Here's a nicer version with typeclasses ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xCaI4O0SSp2M4IPIegK7fQ)):

```
val fPerson: ((String, Int)) => Person = Person.apply _

opaque type Extract[GT <: Tuple, RT <: Tuple] = GT => RT
given Extract[EmptyTuple, EmptyTuple] = Predef.identity
given [A, PG <: Tuple, PR <: Tuple](using p: Extract[PG, PR])
   as Extract[Get[A] *: PG, A *: PR] = {
  case h *: t => h.get *: p(t)
}

def genericF[GT <: Tuple, RT <: Tuple, B](
    f: RT => B,
    t: GT
)(using extract: Extract[GT, RT]): Get[B] = Put(f(extract(t)))
```

---

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KWuRdY7uRKiOURBPx7EUrA)'s one way you could implement `genericF` using `Tuple.InverseMap` (note that I switched the two parameters to `genericF`:

```scala
val fPerson: ((String, Int)) => Person = Person.apply _

type ExtractG = [G] =>> G match {
  case Get[a] => a
}

type AllGs[T <: Tuple] = T match {
  case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  case Get[_] *: t => AllGs[t]
  case _ => Nothing
}

def extract[T <: Tuple](t: T)(using AllGs[T]): Tuple.InverseMap[T, Get] =
  t.map {
    [G] => (g: G) => g.asInstanceOf[Get[_]].get.asInstanceOf[ExtractG[G]]
  }.asInstanceOf[Tuple.InverseMap[T, Get]]

def genericF[B](
    t: Tuple,
    f: Tuple.InverseMap[t.type, Get] => B
)(using AllGs[t.type]): Get[B] = Put(f(extract(t)))

val person: Get[Person] = genericF(t, fPerson)
```

`ExtractG` is to make the `PolyFunction` compile, because it requires you apply a type constructor to its type parameter.

`AllGs` is to verify that the tuple consists only of `Get`s, because as pointed out by Dmytro Mitin, it isn't typesafe otherwise. If it's all `Get`s, the type becomes `DummyImplicit`, which Scala provides for us. Otherwise, it's `Nothing`. I guess it could conflict with other implicit/given `Nothing`s in scope, but if you do have one already, you're screwed anyways.

Note that this will work only when you have `Get` and will need some modification if you also want it to work for tuples like `(Put[String], GetSubclass[Int])`.

---

Travis Stevens, the OP, has managed to get the solution above this one to work without creating `AllGs`, by using `IsMappedBy`. This is what they got ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OleTraveler/1RsAVBMkRJmHX8XE4rb7bg/2)):

```
val fPerson: ((String, Int)) => Person = Person.apply _

type ExtractG = [G] =>> G match {
  case Get[a] => a
}

def extract[T <: Tuple, I <: Tuple.InverseMap[T, Get]](
    t: T
  )(using Tuple.IsMappedBy[Get][T]): I =
  t.map {
    [G] => (g: G) => g.asInstanceOf[Get[_]].get.asInstanceOf[ExtractG[G]]
  }.asInstanceOf[I]

def genericF[T <: Tuple, I <: Tuple.InverseMap[T, Get], B](
    t: T,
    f: I => B
)(using Tuple.IsMappedBy[Get][T]): Get[B] = Put(f(extract(t)))
```

---

And here's one using dependent types, just for fun ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gzS6vvBdTNOLqTkx6FgPrw)):

```scala
type Extract[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match {
  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
  case Get[a] *: t => a *: Extract[t]
}
 
type AllGs[T <: Tuple] = T match {
  case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  case Get[_] *: t => AllGs[t]
  case _ => Nothing
}

def genericF[T <: Tuple : AllGs, B](
    t: T,
    f: Extract[t.type] => B
): Get[B] = {
  def extract[T <: Tuple](t: T): Extract[T] = t match {
    case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
    case (head *: tail): (Get[_] *: _) => head.get *: extract(tail)
  }
  Put(f(extract(t)))
}
```

I was hoping `Extract` wouldn't compile for tuples like `(Put("foo"), 3)`, but unfortunately, `AllGs` is still necessary.

Comment: `extract` is not type-safe. If we call `extract((1, 2))` it will compile but throw `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: @DmytroMitin How about now? Probably abusing `DummyImplicit`, but it appears to work

Comment: Pretty inventively :) I'm a little puzzled that we use advanced type machinery and still have to use a lot of `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: Just throwing this out there as I'm still working through this, but would IsMappedBy be a replacement for AllGs?

Comment: @user Yeah, good old `Comapped` + `NatTRel` :) https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L91-L156

Comment: @TravisStevens I [tried](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmkzRNkFT0u82dhInKM15g) with IsMappedBy but had to explicitly provide type arguments for `genericF`. Perhaps you'll have more luck.

Comment: @user I was able get your example to work with IsMappedBy by making the `Tuple.InverseMap[T, Get]` a type parameter [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OleTraveler/1RsAVBMkRJmHX8XE4rb7bg/2) .

Comment: @TravisStevens Nice! Mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: @user InverseMap[T,Get] only works if the Tuple is down cast to a Tuple of Gets eg. `(Get[String], Get[Int])` like they are in your example.  InverseMap does not work if we keep the original types: `(Put[String], Put[Int])`.  However, using the AllGs approach presented, does indeed work.  For my use case, it is vital to keep the original types, so in my project I am using the equivalent to AllGs.