# dotty / scala3 unmap a mapped tuple type to its constituent types

Tags: scala, tuples, dotty, scala-3

im having trouble unmapping a mapped tuple to its constituent types. How can i implement the `read` method of `Impl[T]` in a typesafe way? currently I am just doing it with `Tuple.toArray` / `Tuple.fromArray`

```
trait Reader[A]:

  def read: A


object Reader:

  def apply[T <: Tuple] (columns: Tuple.Map[T, Reader]): Reader[T] = Impl(columns)

  private class Impl[T <: Tuple](columns: Tuple.Map[T, Reader]) extends Reader[T]:

    def read: T = ???
```

Edit (1): added not typesafe code

```
  private class Impl[T <: Tuple](columns: Tuple.Map[T, Reader]) extends Reader[T]:
    def read: T = 
      val array = 
        columns
          .toArray
          .asInstanceOf[Array[Reader[_]]]
      val read = array.map(_.read)
      val tuple = 
        Tuple
          .fromArray(read)
          .asInstanceOf[T]
      tuple
```

Edit (2): current incomplete attempt - contains a PolyFunction error

```
extension [F[_], T <: Tuple] (mapped: Tuple.Map[T, F]):

  def unmap(f: [a] => F[a] => a): T = ???

object Reader:

  private class Impl[T <: Tuple](columns: Tuple.Map[T, Reader]) extends Reader[T]:

    def read: T = 
      val read_column: [a] => Reader[a] => a = [a] => (reader: Reader[a]) => reader.read
      val tuple: T = columns.unmap(read_column)
      tuple
```

Comment: [This works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kHgtkL3uQvOYN471KTWwOw), but there's a lot of casts and you probably won't like it.

Comment: yeah not ideal, just hiding the dragons at a different level

Comment: something similar in the actual dotty codebase uses casts as well. https://git.io/JL3G0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala 3 - InverseMap on First Order Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339583/scala-3-inversemap-on-first-order-type). I just realized I've already answered practically the same question. I think it should solve your problem, so I've also deleted my answer here.

Comment: hm there is still a fair amount of casting there, need to see if it is actually relevant. I saw the types (InverseMap/IsMappedBy), but there were no clear methods in Tuple that actually were able to consume those. to be fair at first glance, i liked your answer better

Comment: The bottom two solutions have casting, the top one does not. [Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/s7CIjE4vQoypWV7GxnlylA) the Scastie I made for your question. It's got no casting, just typeclasses.

Comment: youre right, same setup to your recursively created extractor. thanks!